# Modify and switch positions of floating elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

How would one go about modifying the positions of floating elements? Is it possible with simple HTML/CSS? If not, what would be the simplest way using JavaScript w/ and/or w/o jQuery?

Example: [http://jsbin.com/ufeme3/2](http://goo.gl/XFvcs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to pick first element and put it after third using `insertAfter` method. Them pick fourth element and insert before first element in row using `insertBefore`. But using that method could cause situation, where elements will be in incorrect places for a while in moment of rearranging.

Second way could look like this:

1. Wrap all 5 elements in some wrapper with `position: relative`.
2. Before switching elements take the position (jQuery's `position` method for example) of each element and set it for them(`top`, `left` etc.), additionally adding `position: absolute` to them.
3. Hide first and fourth element - other elements will stay at their positions, because they positioned absolutely.
4. Put removed elements in correct places.
5. Remove previously added css properties.

Elements should stay in their places and be replaced without moving others.